# Ordered Dictionary with list as values

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I want to create an ordered dictionary with a `List` as the value type.

I tried to call this method:

```
ordered = collections.OrderedDict(list)
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Is there any other data structure I can use for an ordered dictionary?

Later in the program I need to get the first key/value pair that was inserted; that's why I need the list ordered. After that point order does not matter.

Comment: You are confusing the way `defaultdict` is used with `OrderedDict`. You do not give a factory function to `OrderedDict` You would construct an `OrderedDict` the same way as a regular dict -- but the insertion order is preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the confusion. It seems more like the OP believes that giving `list` to the `OrderedDict` constructor is like a type annotation, declaring what type the values will have. I don't think the OP means for `list` as a constructor to be called or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed. You don't need to specify the value type in advance, you just insert objects of that type when needed.

For example:

```
ordered = collections.OrderedDict()
ordered[123] = [1,2,3]
```

You can get the first inserted key/value with `next(ordered.iteritems())` (Python 2) or `next(ordered.items())` (Python 3).

Comment: can I use ordered.items()[0] ?

Comment: @user3264659 Only in Python 2, and it will be slower for large dicts.